# Wrong search box position when Select2 dropdown opens above in VueJs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, vue.js

This Image link is showing the issue with Reporting To dropdown with Wrong search box position. This application is written in Vuejs.

Here I'm using Select2 plugin for the dropdown. 
I need to fix this issue in vuejs.

Image Link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/j37e0.png

I'm trying to implement this from the following link https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4614

But it is throwing console error for this methods_resizeDropdown, _positionDropdown.

```
var select2Instance = $(selectNode).data('select2');
select2Instance.on('results:message', function(params){
this.dropdown._resizeDropdown();
this.dropdown._positionDropdown();
});
```

Here the following code is select2 component in the application.

```
<template>
    <div class="single-select">
        <select class="select2" :disabled="disabled" multiple="multiple" v-if="multiple">
             <slot></slot>
         </select>
         <select class="select2" :disabled="disabled" v-else>
            <slot></slot>
         </select>
     </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
    name: 'ob-select2',
    props: {
        disabled: Boolean,
        options: Object,
        value: [String, Array],
        multiple: Boolean,
        inModal: Boolean,
        initialData:[Array]
    },

    computed: {
        config() {
            let o = this.options
            Object.assign(o, {theme: "onblick"})

            return o
        },

        el() {
            return jquery(this.$el).find("select")
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.init()

    },

    watch: {
        config(value) {
            this.init()
        },
        initialData(){
            if(this.initialData != undefined){
                this.appendInitialData()
            }
        },
        value(value) {
            if(this.multiple) { // For multiple
                value = value && value.length >= 0 ? value : []
                var el = this.el.val() && this.el.val().length >= 0 ? this.el.val() : []
                if ([...value].sort().join(",") != [...el].sort().join(",")) {
                    this.el.val(value).trigger('change')
                }
            } else { // For single
                value = value ? value : ''
                var el = this.el.val() ? this.el.val() : ''

                if(value != el)
                    this.el.val(value).trigger('change')
            }
        }
    },

    methods: {
        init() {
            var vm = this
            if(this.initialData != undefined){
                this.appendInitialData()
            }
            vm.el
              // init select2
              .select2(vm.config)
              .val(vm.value)
              .trigger('change')
              // emit event on change.
              .on('change', function () {
                  vm.$emit('input', vm.el.val())
                  jquery('.select2-selection__rendered').removeAttr('title');
              })
              .on('select2:open',function(){
                  vm.$emit('select2-open')
              })
              .on('select2:close',function(){
                  vm.$emit('select2-close')
              })
            if (vm.inModal) {
                vm.el.on('select2:open', function (e) {
                    jquery(".select2-container").addClass("in-overlay");
                })
                vm.el.on("select2:close", function (e) {
                    jquery(".select2-container").removeClass("in-overlay");
                });
            }
        },

        getSelect2Data() {
            return this.el.select2('data')
        },
        appendInitialData(){               
            if(this.initialData.length != 0){
                this.initialData.forEach((a)=>{
                    let newOption = new Option(a.text,a.id,true,true)
                    this.el.append(newOption).trigger('change')
                })
            }

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How can I resolve this issue using vuejs. I'm using single selection dropdown and dropdown Options will come from ajax call.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and check out [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This is the first on topic question for my google search so I'll answer here. The wrong position of the dropdown occurs the first time you click the dropdown and the first time you click the dropdown after a search that has no results. Your particular error with the methods not found is because you named your data attribute select2. Name it something else.

[Here is a workaround](https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/issues/41#issuecomment-310825598) that seems to work for many people (including me). My implementation below:

```
    // data-select2 conflicts with library code. data-something-select2 works
    // set the dropdownParent to fix positioning error
    // https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/issues/41#issuecomment-310825598
    $("select[data-use-select2]").each(function() {
        $(this).select2({
            theme: "bootstrap4",
            dropdownParent: $(this).parent()
        });
    });
```